# Is it true that "X need not have done it"="It wasn't necessary for X to do it but X did it"?

Tags: modal-verbs

> Is it true that "X need not have done it"="It wasn't necessary for X to do it but X did it"?

My textbook (and consequently my English teacher) claims and insists that the equality is strict and that you cannot, e.g., use "X need not have done it" having in mind "It wasn't necessary for X to do it and I've said nothing about whether X actually did it".

Is this really true?

If this is indeed true, I feel this is a weird convention and I don't agree with it.
The modal verb "need not" simply just intuitively means 'it is not necessary', and the additional constraint for the action to actually be done is unnatural in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, it's odd. But "disagreeing with it" will not get you anywhere. Knowing how to use it like a native, on the other hand, will.  Just file it away in your mental list of inconsistencies, illogicalities, and other oddities in English; you'll find plenty.

Answer (score 1):

It does imply that *it* was done, but not necessarily by X.

Consider this scenario:

> *The door was left open and all the animals escaped from the barn.*
>
> SON: The only person it could have been is that no-good Charles from next door. He's always sneaking in there.
>
> FATHER:  No, Charles need not have done it, it could have been the wind from the storm last night.

Comment: +1. Yes, that was what I was thinking too--that some speakers can also use it in that way.

Comment: It could be used this way, but I (an AmE native speaker) don't think I have ever used it or heard it used this way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for sure we say *need not have + past participle* when we mean that the thing was done. This is for sure. And this is the overwhelming use (and from that) the practical meaning of the construction. But  technically does it have to mean that the person did it. I don't know. But this is the meaning we assign to the construction.

And we use *did not need + Infinitive* when this assumption is not there.

Consider this quote from, MacMillan Dictionary of, [a usage comment](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/need_1)

> The modal verb **need** has no past tense, but it can be used in the pattern **need not have/needn’t have** followed by a past participle, to show that although someone did something, it was not necessary: You needn’t have waited for me.

It's very hard to conceive of using this phrase with the sense that the person did not actually do the thing.

Thus
*need* as a modal verb used in this pattern, *ie* 'you need not have done it' is almost always (perhaps always  if it has become to have a fixed meaning) used to mean:

'You didn't have to do it, but you did it.' (which makes me think of a [song by ZZTop](http://The%20modal%20verb%20need%20has%20no%20past%20tense,%20but%20it%20can%20be%20used%20in%20the%20pattern%20need%20not%20have/needn%E2%80%99t%20have%20followed%20by%20a%20past%20participle,%20to%20show%20that%20although%20someone%20did%20something,%20it%20was%20not%20necessary:%20You%20needn%E2%80%99t%20have%20waited%20for%20me.), for some reason)--but you need not pay attention to that parenthetical remark.

The modal verb *need* means *to be under necessity or obligation*.

You need to clean your room. = You have to clean your room. You must clean your room.

In the present *need not* means *to be under necessity or obligation* and can be translated with *don't have to/doesn't have to*.

> "You need not listen to it" = "You do not have to listen to it."

The basic meaning of the modal as "being under obligation" remains when used to help express a past state. This is, to my knowledge, nowadays used only with *need not*.

So, *need not* means *did not have to* or *were/was not under the obligation*.

In the pattern *need not* + *have* + *past participle*, the expression does mean:

You didn't have to, but you did.

> You need not have bought that new diamond ring for me, (but you did) and I love you so much for doing so."

the equivalent to

> "You did't have to buy that diamond ring for me, (but you did) and I love you so much for doing so."

Another example:

> Jane need not have liked this answer, but she did.

equivalent to:

> Jane did not have to like this answer, but she did.

Comment: (Since you asked so cleverly ;)  Evelyn didn't have to like this answer, but she did.